# Best way to add a property to JSON without reading in memory

Tags: java, spring, jackson, gson

I have a large JSON and complex file (~100MB). I need to add a property to it without reading in memory. I am unable to find an option to append to JSON without reading the entire content in memory.

I couldn't find any suitable example.

The best I could think of is to replace the last `}` with `"key":"value"}` using `StreamReader`(s) and `StreamReader`(s)

The JSON is read through a legacy application and we are integrating it to a web application and hence this is becoming a bottleneck.

Comment: And what have you implemented already to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3):

If you are unwilling to parse data, I think you should use `Java.io.RandomAccessFile`. The package will allow you to seek to the end of the file, (or 1 before the end), and write your new data. Keep in mind, the writer overrwrites strings, it does not insert them, so assuming you want to add `"key": property,`, you'll need to remember to insert `,"key": property}`

Comment: Thanks, but `java.io.RandomAccessFile` will be slow. An `ObjectMapper` will be relatively faster than `RandomAccessFile`.

Comment: `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` will be much faster than `RandomAccessFile`. However, I've used `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` to create a temp file and move once I've a temp file.

Comment: @Mansoor No, `RandomAccessFile` won't be slow as it allows seeking huge files from the very end, and also provides a way to open a file output stream using a file handle at a specific position; _doesn't really matter_ how big the input file is. `ObjectMapper` will be slower as it's input-oriented and it has at least to parse token by token, and it also requires a source file and a target file at the same file (where most of the work is copying tokens, not appending).

Comment: @Carson I wish I could upvote your answer one more time, as I really appreciate the idea of parsing the very end of the given file by opening a `RandomAccessFile` instance that does not require parsing entire file.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking of full-featured streaming from an input stream to an output stream (therefore reading and writing token by token from the very beginning), but since you mentioned you can access a file, @[Carson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4930913/carson)'s suggestion is indeed wa-a-ay better than my initial idea. I only developed this idea further:

```java
public final class JsonAppender
        extends Writer {

    private final BufferedWriter writer;
    private final char terminator;

    private boolean isAboutToWrite = true;

    private JsonAppender(final BufferedWriter writer, final char terminator) {
        this.writer = writer;
        this.terminator = terminator;
    }

    public static Writer appendAtEnd(final RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile)
            throws IOException {
        long pos = randomAccessFile.length() - 1;
        char terminator = '\u0000';
        outer_whitespace:
        for ( ; pos >= 0; pos-- ) {
            randomAccessFile.seek(pos);
            final char ch = (char) randomAccessFile.readByte();
            switch ( ch ) {
// @formatter:off
            case ' ': case '\r': case '\n': case '\t':
// @formatter:on
                continue;
// @formatter:off
            case ']': case '}':
// @formatter:on
                terminator = ch;
                break outer_whitespace;
            default:
                throw new IOException("Unexpected " + ch + " at " + pos);
            }
        }
        if ( pos < 0 ) {
            throw new IOException("No object or array begin found");
        }
        inner_whitespace:
        for ( pos -= 1; pos >= 0; pos-- ) {
            randomAccessFile.seek(pos);
            final char ch = (char) randomAccessFile.readByte();
            switch ( ch ) {
// @formatter:off
            case ' ': case '\r': case '\n': case '\t':
// @formatter:on
                continue;
// @formatter:off
            case '}': case ']':
            case '\"':
            case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4': case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
            case 'e': // for both true and false
            case 'l': // for null
// @formatter:on
                break inner_whitespace;
            default:
                throw new IOException("Unexpected " + ch + " at " + pos);
            }
        }
        return new JsonAppender(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(randomAccessFile.getFD()))), terminator);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final char[] buffer, final int offset, final int length)
            throws IOException {
        if ( isAboutToWrite ) {
            isAboutToWrite = false;
            writer.write(',');
        }
        writer.write(buffer, offset, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush()
            throws IOException {
        writer.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
            throws IOException {
        writer.write(terminator);
        writer.close();
    }

}
```

And an example test (assuming the test is running in a stopwatch-friendly environment, like IntelliJ IDEA -- see next):

```java
public final class JsonAppenderTest {

    @RepeatedTest(10)
    public void testAppendAtEnd()
            throws IOException {
        try ( final RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(LARGE_JSON_PATH, "rw");
                final Writer writer = JsonAppender.appendAtEnd(randomAccessFile) ) {
            final String json = new JSONObject(ImmutableMap.of("foo", "bar")).toString();
            CharStreams.copy(new StringReader(json), writer);
        }
    }

}
```

How it all works: the appending writer attempts to skip possible whitespaces first starting from the very end of the given file, and then it attempts to detect the terminating character (`}` or `]`, depends on the document), and then it attempts to detect the last value to append a new value after (with possible whitespaces). After that once the writing position is found, it merely creates a buffered reader for the given file descriptor that is already configured to write at that position. And once the writer is closed, the terminating character is written to the file output stream, and then the underlying stream is closed as well.

Here are example results for 10 appends in a row (the test is written poorly in terms of proper benchmarking, but this is fine enough here), the input file size is about 24 MB (three times bigger than yours):

- ~30..40ms for the first test run (warming JVM, etc)
- ~1..2ms per each test run from 2nd to 10th
- ~40ms for 10 test runs in total

Running your solution produces about ~500ms per each test run (and about 5s for 10 test runs in total). Also note that your solution creates a new big file on each run, therefore making it very resource consuming and suboptimal (and even slower as the input file size grows), whilst using `RandomAccessFile` with some low-level parsing is really fast and only *appends* necessary data to the very end.

Again, thanks to [Carson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4930913/carson) for the great idea!

Comment: Thank you fluffy. I appreciate the efforts. As much as I liked Carson's idea, it wasn't suitable for my immediate use case. As you rightly mentioned, for a full-fledged streaming solutions, `RandomAccessFile` would be better.

Comment: And I am very much aware of creating a copy on each `addInt`. But I would peform this operation once. So, it works. But I am making a library, so I'll re-structure it.

Comment: did you get a chance to validate if the JSON formed is correct?

Comment: `{{"foo":1},{"foo":1},{"foo":1},{"foo":1},{"foo":1},{"foo":1},{"foo":1},{"foo":1},{"foo":1},{"foo":1}}` this is the JSON that it produces.

Comment: @Mansoor Absolutely. The 24 MB file I used for the test was a huge array I downloaded from a random GitHub repository. Again, read the code carefully: it tries to detect **the last** array element or object property of a non-empty array or object (the type of the outer-most literal stored in the `terminator`), and then **always** appends a `,` and then **delegates** writing where one can write anything, and writing the terminator on `close`.

Comment: @Mansoor Also, if you're going to write an object property, please write both property name and value using the `write` method. The example above is used for arrays only, for simplicity. The appender is dumb, and it only detects where to start the write procedure from, then working similarly to your `addInt`. Writing a _good_ backwards parser is obviously time consuming, and obviously out of scope of the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I realized. I've written a wrapper around your code. Please see the edit.

Comment: Yes, I've written a wrapper around your code. Thanks

Comment: @Mansoor Thanks for double granting-revoking the b/a. It was lovely.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a wrapper around @fluffy's and @Carson's answer.

```
public class JsonStream extends Writer {
    private final BufferedWriter writer;
    private final char terminator;

    private boolean isAboutToWrite = true;

    private JsonStream(final BufferedWriter writer, final char terminator) {
        this.writer = writer;
        this.terminator = terminator;
    }

    public static Writer appendAtEnd(final RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile)
            throws IOException {
        long pos = randomAccessFile.length() - 1;
        char terminator = '\u0000';
        outer_whitespace:
        for ( ; pos >= 0; pos-- ) {
            randomAccessFile.seek(pos);
            final char ch = (char) randomAccessFile.readByte();
            switch ( ch ) {
// @formatter:off
                case ' ': case '\r': case '\n': case '\t':
// @formatter:on
                    continue;
// @formatter:off
                case ']': case '}':
// @formatter:on
                    terminator = ch;
                    break outer_whitespace;
                default:
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected " + ch + " at " + pos);
            }
        }
        if ( pos < 0 ) {
            throw new IOException("No object or array begin found");
        }
        inner_whitespace:
        for ( pos -= 1; pos >= 0; pos-- ) {
            randomAccessFile.seek(pos);
            final char ch = (char) randomAccessFile.readByte();
            switch ( ch ) {
// @formatter:off
                case ' ': case '\r': case '\n': case '\t':
// @formatter:on
                    continue;
// @formatter:off
                case '}': case ']':
                case '\"':
                case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4': case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
                case 'e': // for both true and false
                case 'l': // for null
// @formatter:on
                    break inner_whitespace;
                default:
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected " + ch + " at " + pos);
            }
        }
        return new JsonStream(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(randomAccessFile.getFD()))), terminator);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final char[] buffer, final int offset, final int length)
            throws IOException {
        if ( isAboutToWrite ) {
            isAboutToWrite = false;
            writer.write(',');
        }
        writer.write(buffer, offset, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush()
            throws IOException {
        writer.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
            throws IOException {
        writer.write(terminator);
        writer.close();
    }

}
```

```
public class JsonStreamAppender extends Writer {

    final File file;
    final Map<String,Object> map;
    final Writer writer;
    public JsonStreamAppender(File file) throws IOException {
        this.file=file;
        map=new LinkedHashMap<>();
        final RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), "rw");
        writer= JsonStream.appendAtEnd(randomAccessFile);
    }

    public void add(String key,int value) throws IOException {
        map.put(key,value);
        this.append();
    }



    private void append() throws IOException {
        final String json = new JSONObject(ImmutableMap.copyOf(map)).toString();
        CharStreams.copy(new StringReader(json.substring(1,json.length()-1)), writer);
    }

    /**
     * Writes a portion of an array of characters.
     *
     * @param cbuf Array of characters
     * @param off  Offset from which to start writing characters
     * @param len  Number of characters to write
     * @throws IOException If an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        writer.write(cbuf,off,len);
    }

    /**
     * Flushes the stream.  If the stream has saved any characters from the
     * various write() methods in a buffer, write them immediately to their
     * intended destination.  Then, if that destination is another character or
     * byte stream, flush it.  Thus one flush() invocation will flush all the
     * buffers in a chain of Writers and OutputStreams.
     *
     * <p> If the intended destination of this stream is an abstraction provided
     * by the underlying operating system, for example a file, then flushing the
     * stream guarantees only that bytes previously written to the stream are
     * passed to the operating system for writing; it does not guarantee that
     * they are actually written to a physical device such as a disk drive.
     *
     * @throws IOException If an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Closes the stream, flushing it first. Once the stream has been closed,
     * further write() or flush() invocations will cause an IOException to be
     * thrown. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.
     *
     * @throws IOException If an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

And Test cases

```
    @RepeatedTest(10)
    public void testAppendAtEndAppender(){
        try(JsonStreamAppender jsonStreamAppender=new JsonStreamAppender(new File(LARGE_JSON_PATH))){
            jsonStreamAppender.add("operationalLife",-1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```